# auto populate form text fields and drop down lists

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form (made up from HTML/PHP/javascript & jquery) which has a basic structure like this:

```
<p>
<h3>*Work Order #</h3> <input class="desc" type='text' name='number' required />
</p>
<p>
<h3>*Word Order description:</h3> <input class="desc" type='text' name='name' required /><input value="Assesment" type='checkbox' name='asse' /> Assesment?
</p>
<p>
<h3>*Airport Code:</h3> <select name='code' class="list"></select>
<h3>*Airline Code:</h3> <select name='acode' class="alist"></select>
</p>
```

The two list boxes are auto-populated using jquery.

Everything in the list currently is being manually entered....and I want to keep that. However, the first thing most of us do is populate the 'Work Order Description' field...with something that has a format like this:

WO # 240955 / BBB / CA/  V4.2_R_6_68_03

Most of the values in here can populate other fields...like there BBB can be used for Airport code and the CA for airline code. The 240955 for Work order #.

My question is...what can I use that as soon as they copy paste the "WO # 240955 / BBB / CA/  V4.2_R_6_68_03" into the 'Work Order Description' field, it will try and populate the other fields for them?

Thanks

Comment: Exploding the work order string by slashes and then .val to populate the other fields would be a good idea